# Finding the fixed points of an autonomous vector field

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to find the fixed points of the following autonomous vector field:

\begin{align*} \dot x & = \mu x - y -x(x^2+y^2)^3 \\ 
\dot y & = x+\mu y-y(x^2+y^2)^3 \qquad (x.y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \end{align*}

It is clear to me that $(0,0)$ is a fixed point but I'm not sure about how to find the others.

Comment: Well, I am not surprised by the difficulty: you are after the roots of a 2-variable polynomial of degree 6.  Try to understand the geometry of the vector field (e.g., graph it) and the contribution of each summand in the right-hand sides; e.g., look also at the field: $\dot{x} = -x(x^2+y^2)^3, \; \dot{y} = -y(x^2+y^2)^3$.  This one has no zeros except at the origin.  Examine the other summands, too.  How does the field change under the transformation $(x, y) \mapsto (-y, x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the system to polar coordinates.